# MongoDB fails to authenticate Mongo Docker Container in a Dotnet7 Core App

Tags: mongodb, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I have a microservice architecture in my dotnet core webapi app. I haev two services: postgres and mongo
I am running both docker containers with docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    container_name: container-postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
    volumes:
      - 'container-postgresql-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    image: 'postgres:10.4'
    networks:
      - container-network
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INIT_DB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INIT_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass 
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/var/lib/mongodb/data
    networks:
      - container-network

volumes:
  container-postgresql-volume:
  mongodata:
networks:
  container-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My appsetting.Development.json file is:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
    }
  },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "mongodb://root:mypass@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin"
 }
}
```

Lastly my Program.cs file:

[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C67Oq.png)

My Docker Desktop:
[Docker Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jpQ6.png)

**But I am getting error: Unhandled exception. MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.
---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..**

I tried changing connection string, restarted docker containers, deleted docker containers and rebuilt them. I added some firewall configurations to allow connections. Deleted volumes and network bridges and rebuilt them. I rebooted my system couple of times. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was I already installed MongoDB on my local machine that is why it was taking care of the credentials I provided for local Mongo database. I uninstalled MongoDB and it works just fine.